# SQL Server - Client Version

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and trying to familiarize myself with it, so I have some questions.

My background is Oracle and am wondering if it works very similar to SQL Server.

On a client machine we need to install a client version of Oracle, and with the installation it comes with a TNSNames.ORA file which has settings for all of the Oracle DB's which are located on an Oracle DB server.

I would assume that SQL server would follow something similar, install a client version of SQL server? If so, does SQL Server has something similar to local Oracle?

I've found how connect to SQL server from another computer, just wondering if I still would need a slim down/client version of SQL Server, I would assume yes.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.110).aspx

Some of you might be asking, why don't you try it, don't have my second computer yet, would like this info. ahead of time.

Thank you

Comment: I doubt you really "install a client version of Oracle". You mean you're installing a *client* capable of connecting to Oracle -- this is not the same thing as a database engine. If you really do mean a local version of SQL Server, that's SQL Server Express, but installing that is not required to connect to servers, no more than Oracle Express needs to be installed to connect to Oracle servers.

Comment: Jeroen, we call it at work 'Oracle client' and no we don't install Oracle Express, just a version that is capable of connecting to Oracle. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server client APIs include the low-level components needed to connect to and use SQL Server so there is generally no need to install other connectivity components. To name a few Microsoft ones:

- ODBC: Latest version is ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server
- OLE DB: Latest is SQL Server 2012 Native Client
- .Net Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient): included .NET framework
- JDBC: Latest Microsoft version is 6.2

There are also a number of other open source and commercial APIs available for use in various programming languages and development frameworks (e.g. Tedious for Node.js).

Comment: That is good to know, so I won't have to install a client that is capable of connecting to the SQL Server DB. We currently use TOAD for Oracle and I see that TOAD is also available for SQL Server, do you know of other tools? I see SQL Server management and I also see ApexSQL. Machine # 1 will be my developing machine and machine # 2 will have SQL Server. Thank you for your help.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the most commonly used tool. It's a free download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms and supports all modern SQL Server versions, including Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2017 (currently RC1).

Comment: Thanks for all your help Dan, much appreciated.